# Assign multiple roles , overlapping capabilities

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

What happens if i assign let's say 2 different (custom) roles to a user that both of which have the same (custom) capability?

Comment: user will have all the capabilities. Why would you want to do this in the first place you should just make one custom role with all the capabilities needed to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JacobRambo : it seems quite reasonable to me to have Roles share capabilities.

Comment: That seems reasonable to me too. But the OP is asking about assigning a user multiple roles. What would be the need for a user to have more than one role? I didn't even think that it was possible by default to do that in wordpress.

Comment: If you understand "Roles" as "groupings of capabilities" which is the only way they make sense to me, then it is not hard to imagine wanting to put someone in two different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that nothing would happen other than the user would have the capability in question.

Think about it. The [default Roles share many capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)-- Authors, Editors, and Administrators all have `edit_posts`, for example. All roles (usually) have `read`

The same system manages both default and custom roles/capabilities, so there really should be no problem.